# Dropbox /previews not working

Tags: curl, dropbox-api

I'm trying to get the file [preview](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#previews) using:

```
curl "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/previews/auto/Get Started with Dropbox.pdf" -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS-TOKEN>"
```

But it always return:

```
{"error": "no_preview.file_content."}
```

Please advise if there is anything wrong with my approach.

---

**Update**

Trying with [/files (GET)](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET):

```
curl "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/auto/Get Started with Dropbox.pdf" -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS-TOKEN"
```

And it return the content (download the file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#previews:

> Previews are only generated for the files with the following
>   extensions: .doc, .docx, .docm, .ppt, .pps, .ppsx, .ppsm, .pptx,
>   .pptm, .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm, .rtf

PDF isn't on the list.

Comment: But I saw in the document their state for the return data:
`Data that represents a preview of the file. The Content-Type header will be either application/pdf or text/html. There is a Original-Content-Length header which contains the size of the preview data.`

Comment: Just curious, why dropbox can provide return data as pdf from extension docx but cannot generate the preview from the pdf extension?

Comment: Nobody said we *couldn't* provide that. But we don't. If you're asking why we don't, it's mostly because it's not that useful... the file is already a PDF.

Comment: Understood, that means that I must use 2 api to get the content `/previews` for the content such as `docx, pptx, xlsx, etc` and using `/files (GET)` to get `pdf` file content.