# Displaying Return Data From Dropbox API Previews

Tags: javascript, python, html, dropbox-api

I'm attempting to use dropbox's preview function for word and other supported documents but cannot make sense of the data it's returning. The documentation says it returns a preview for a file as either application/pdf or text/html. I seem to be getting the text/html as far as I can tell by the header although internally it seems to be coming through in some sort of pdf markup. I've included the returns from 'content' and 'header' at the bottom. I can get 'text' too but the three are greater than 30000 characters combined.

I want to display the preview in an iframe or something of the sort but cannot make sense of the pdf markup. When I try to frame it it just displays as plain text the way you see it below minus the html markup. I can't figure out how to display it as a pdf or in any other way. It opens up that same jibberish way in the browser as well if attempted that way. If there's any other good way to use dropbox's preview I would be open to it.

This answer to this is somewhat related.
[Dropbox /previews not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777188/dropbox-previews-not-working)

I'm using the python api and previews function found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#previews

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
-Abe

Update in response to comment. Here's a link to the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hh3uwvdkjmc7ty/Agenda%207-14-2015.docx?dl=0

And here's the python:

```
import requests

client = DropboxClient(ACCESS_TOKEN)
(url, params, headers) = client.request('/previews/auto' + FILE_PATH, method = 'GET', content_server = True)

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print r.content
```

Content

```
<!-- saved from url=(0026)http://localhost:5000/test -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>%PDF-1.4
%�쏢
5 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
endobj

xref
5 15
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000608 00000 n 
0000000672 00000 n 
0000000851 00000 n 
0000001153 00000 n 
0000001172 00000 n 
0000001214 00000 n 
0000001247 00000 n 
0000001449 00000 n 
0000001650 00000 n 
0000001681 00000 n 
0000001712 00000 n 
0000001744 00000 n 
0000010388 00000 n 
0000010687 00000 n 

trailer
&lt;<c7635ddd2c9579cc73483074c45ac3d9>]/Prev 15063&gt;&gt;
startxref
0
%%EOF

6 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
endobj
7 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
/Contents 8 0 R
&gt;&gt;
endobj
8 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
stream
x�MO�N1��|Dʤ�q�ul�H4t��8���ړ���do�;��3��!{���4��O��K���V�/��\&gt;6L����������zAi��}����*�p���b"Ȋf�:"S�������:+_���&lt;�h�p�SU*�ÓӉ���&amp;L5��T@��9&lt;�K���c�L|����h��cbP���RČ�SLT)<w� �gn���&�p��~���mt��[e~endstream="" endobj="" 9="" 0="" obj="" 232="" 10="" <<="" type="" extgstate="" opm="" 1="">&gt;endobj
11 0 obj
[/ICCBased
1 0 R]endobj
12 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
endobj
13 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
endobj
14 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
endobj
15 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
endobj
16 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
endobj
17 0 obj
&lt;&gt;stream
x��}
XSg��y��            $"��/ �D\  ��h-$*Z?�Rk?�8�Ѫm�Z�N���8۝}�`g��N�t:��+3�t�;�ٙjkg�V+��ӱSa�{��h���������'������������
���~`!0���g%���u���k�"�ܽ��Ʋ�GP��zbe��u�I[�@�@۱j��-���3��Z{��p&gt;ǋ���Y��p�p�6-*+zP��bѮH�̞u}���|1__���+�/?�Տ���қuS�wL*m��֭���K��M}�|�Z�{�����(�2���!@�����q�(G���&lt;16�
Je�x�U[B[q��81Ɯ�đ�5���g�QT��Cl�T���a{/�s�������O�U�g�!���I�nD�]�`��A��~�����Y�a!,��X��±H���L�h�PD���"_b�Ǿ2�C8ʭ0�#=��_5&lt;���:�&lt; -�sW��$z���5�   ���m��#i��vh��qn�h���G_'�iX�p��A;&lt;�|TLݩ��dfL�'���3}�vf�}p7&lt;��O������_��Gp��&gt;���l��&amp;��/=Ϡ�~��ق��m܏'�ɂGal%Z�<gj������ �ž�}~��n�p���6��|g�z}s�kb�o��b_���˙���e_؂�5�v\�v�w݆�q��\*h5��]�)�s���{`="��bxv3܉���گó��n��I.\����*���y���@㒘0N06�/h��@">dJ2ᕩ�q�8��g�)���1b%,|ga�8�4ܹ<x�2��y����0ÿ����-�(vp�ү����kφ�)�c|mezc�� ����;�t�}���k�8׫�.�u�j6�gπ�qg�~⍉qi�q����i�_1���܊ge��="">Ç���=�;�l�NA&amp;&gt;䞊�Ɨ�ϰ�F�CH�´��m�+�yŉ��ώ�)�����w�]�o�K�)�ރ7ѳ_�߱���س�'\�S*F����vx�����\���sE��Oû�n»*���-x���@L ��b�"�~�~���Qk��ۉg�Cx���xEp��Λ�,��v�ϝ��&lt;�iV����V����̜ᮜ^Q^�*-)v��y�9�Y���-=-u�5�bN6�z]|�V�V�(�( f�\�kX#Z����u�m�v��\� V��`s9���Z��!�ELj�
�P����U��l��;6�k�5�\~�]A1��gw�߲N�����R��ۭ"����X���.[PԷ��n
kf�����x��Pi�#m��ir����$O��4r�4瑐~Pk����4�wE0�jc��&gt;�sy��%�7p�$��$��8�|��ٙ�ؠ!���\�
��t,lQ�-d��.�I�����5������I���h���$�j"  ��a� �84_�n�Q�@��E�aI�Ւቑ�S���RbX
OBT֋1�I�V�B�{l�#���zX��AG��f��va�A`�z:�i-��Q�C!=6��^��ͳ5��B��uH^�����=+�MH���2u�o�}�*&amp; o
�����<gec ��6�="" �v��#8�)�vj�="" �8�p�g�����-qnn�䍳���{�lb��5a���+��="��������`K�aĔ��:�5]t�" kl�="+����jkX㥠" ��a!�^�k�q4\��u}[�]���a(�@���ه��w�oc���o�(th="" :�="��.�?��TXL�ђ��ﷇ���1Y�E[���%&amp;�z�KX6RX���k�Z�ՋL�����z���I51c����5l��������$�`fr��j������:�o�5:�P���" ���'��;lzghp�="" �6lr��?��*6����@�!���f}���ell[b�����="">8j�J��0Y��OGb�c��\H�����jk�G�0�VQ_IC'�Ї1�-��D0V`�V5�?�a�����3#�C����;��i&lt;�`9f��6_8o���!�&lt;�c����%ƅ��_.�lpྙ[�����!�#��vJ���ޠ8ҁk�C����l}b���2���T���(��ɼԐ�O̐�a{�!�yQQ��z�6��:�u�xAx���x��s��"���D����t��ɕX8�H��P �iS���=7^��;py�p}C�����t�EN��FWV{�F�_��g�A"8_k�φ'Fn�$�l=t�E[�+    ~�T��ę���8eZ�qq�a�^�k������o�����[9+EK�/b�Jk$��X��R�-���\7�.��jFGM1_����-���&amp;�UN�&gt;���;�g�֩٦��g��x|l��I��dw۠@v/X�;�_gl�;|Ca�u��L,����K��e��*i�F3�B��!F%շ���RNRH��a�N%�t3a�^�1���:A҅�*�=h�7=(
����=���LaD�vT��8�  �Ԋ��u��QG�5T_�+�&gt;�Q����a��
80�������Swa�l�x����k�Y7#��U�~zq3֛E@�,����΃�)K����~Q5�!V�-��u���(���6�Fg�rH"�18�������V�l6|jr����&gt;�t �?��(��e����25΍��ƊY�6R�g������
��A�tF.�~b�a�
�չ�b��BG�&amp;.VTѻ*F�5E�!~b�����ܮH[/jpF�SLi�����t.�مS�U@�i�v��A:i��,��fw��n�A��Rn�}�$�㥰6��\+��vOw�a��8�v�Q�+�C
�]������^'�C!U܍������TikX��
6�SЌ���]{*�
1 ��q7@��Oˮ5}�����O5��0�p�zp�J�C:�@N���?�6�f�0�B.��d�sY��,���%Y�H.��Y�P~+���9YxOޕ���pFޔ������SY��,���iY8"�ea�,�da�,쒅���D˂_|��!��0GZd�Y*d�X��P(����YP���D?�����%�^���~ ��%zN��I��D#ѷ%���)�Q����k}U��H�e��$�%:"�$�}�����DOH��D�J��D�I�~������$z�D$z�Dw ��m�Rn�D���V�.�h�D[%�$�:��S����j!�D� �#�!6 �!�#�D�@���)"��``�������A��8�C��W���^]ث{ua�.�Յ���W���X�C�.��eX�k�a�2�]18��A\B��C���A,C&lt;�9�b�]"^�\y�ʙ+cW�0cG&amp;^�8316����rY8���#� Ƹ,A˝y~�yF"�Zgǎ���`|X[����aci�S=Mt�DWk�b���6&amp;Y��8�#���|�2��Az  1�&lt;.,`�9cJ���Er��&amp;�]w[��ʛoG����
HnYo�޲~ۭ)}�%��Z�d�j$+z��+z6�X6���@XjK��0��iH��fe-s?��ُ&lt;��a����a؃�%!}�ψ_!8��9q̓����ǶO@��yf�P��}
�G�P��|�ي[�3ۙ�A���N��xfk����$�ogVI|sӐ��
3�CV���̭XN��G=G�7�,q�յ��F� ���a��j̽��y���܁��~���6�twE��"�|C���g6#���"|S�����cI�6E�f�P�Wۊy;)e:���24a��,@&gt;��ϴ�)5�<d�2�0e?ʛ�a�1�� ��2���-h�n�i�����j�0݈��ц���2�j��7��׹p��t�u���xkd="�F�/#f&amp;��`�9]��H};֏�Vv" %�ܵ&�)(��b�t��h���|l��g��a���1ij3�="" ����u�:f="" ]���t��n}fd_�^��="" ��+����="">/�s=.!T��R��bJq�Ɍ����h-�\Ũ�XisT
?g������hps�qsT�9ɸ9*,w`�,܌T�)y
�4
�7"��HFh*��d.]������Vda�߄���&amp;?ǳ�'������2r6�ϐ%~  9��|���}aH��6B������A3&lt;1����mn����%,AS�g8NQ��HZ�CV����i�&amp;�V��LJ�H��Ĉ$�cQb9)��A�PJ�����TE9N�ZJ3���&lt;����[��4���^4LTB"��/�̷Z�bQ������
��'����b�����G��p���������������y�Qw����ں�t���ӳҳ��2Lb�i䑃���y� Ûe结����˃�9RA
���I��(�����i�
�FYdT��C��:�C��)��t`\�j-����IvK��9���"|7�/5܇����P�5�Zr� 9-�9�!y��Rҝ�*-uSv��f8��4i[ÿ�Sܯ��������+��=��1Y�/�5%nJ�j;^(,q����������ν�����ݣ�уN�y���sr(�tr����Z=��4��� +���Dxɚ�&gt;9��qc���*�� ����?����L�}����&gt;B��SQ)u�'���R���{���?����|���%��䒂����ǎp�%4�p���-\��h�#m�a�0+�+=Rw�#���!G�%����ޏ�پ���ଶ���F�
d�� �.Ľ8�Dހ{`��r�4���=@�Ӎ�
��ܘPfԹ��R��Ĩ,6�N#/��].��d��������^����t����m�:P���*^�����:�A���h�1*-�)�xAh�l0�7����FעÓb&amp;x�&gt;��W:�4�F7f����f�1xL}X�KО"��uV�g�I�3�����8��
���|��O/�~YYsY�|��x��e͐���Y�����?z.{&gt;�|�)��{r=ٞLO���I�X=f�ѓ��y��������AĄh��  �u��ofm�b)�"�[��    ��G����x��������K|��B���bK`�~?ϧ�A����T�XJ��~hK�D����ѳ��6�oꋨ0I�`nv����%4�����    �p�H�I&gt;��&gt;'ǹ��S�(#�}��&gt;��뻦�
Ơ��DN�qӵm@^p�J�_��+s����f����
�j����u���-b��ELk]Su-�+��h]"ju�����G?�m��
S�1�P�D�d�����C�|�����s��c�K��"~�xq��]�Y�ě��!�@���(�4�b?b"�؍؅؉X�X��#|�D+b�ь�@#��BDB��A(���O��?�///?�&lt;|/x6�����_��O_�|%�r���������O�'�ǂG�G������C����{�;���m�{�[�˃m��`S�.�����?���0��K&lt;�d��r���Z�,��,7�
R5%Ee��"MAW^y|�+!11�l.*a�f�ԉ��_�5ZjH �n'&gt;�Q����-�����bR^V�L�f�˲�L�����U���0���FG91�
�t�)?39۪���gZ��}�����t��[�1&amp;�����������d��/ϱ8]nGK{Rfi��ҊR]�y��U������i������9��?��&gt;�⻸@|?�õޭX6X(� ��X]:�c��
jXX�~9��Ǧ��ҏ�l��mfs�ݐ�v�������`�I�����6;�-�t9i��8�np��!)�I6�˫�rCx�u܌�&amp;�x��mq֢���8�D�=Ϊ2&gt;�[�p���`��K�٘��))��'gV{8Hp�n�w�։1VdG!J��x<o�z����8 �r�)"�\������5�j49l��b��_#jf4h��v���b�j4�br��eo�)+��7�hk,n<�(&r�h�dz��4q�i���s��fv��="�ĢOLJR�" m6[ju����Ҳ��nbf�䩭�de�p#�="" �dֿ����x�op���p�g�����r�jgfvvyyf:z����q��lf�.��e�jc���*��(g������9}��n칋��-3����uo�0�i9�i�嵢�b������y�-�="">W۳����k�Nk��v�m�*K7iK�+L�jw��n%~���c�8P��"�Sz���Wot%9�N�yH0�2����ؼ�B�&gt;Fy�*;����:�!�q�ʂV�l��4@�'-a�Z��5eElN�tW؋b�s�4Fy
S����vW):˱q�9�Of*������s���Pߏ��[뎷W�;�w��-�Q9���攧%��b�x���\��,�(W_�{�ã�������
I�##���3��K-Ѓ��u�&gt;�a�PgK4��
��a�nט`���%��f�pj�b�L��:�&amp;�M;(h�$9� �))��{c$;|��~��N���
!S�[�/X.�_D,�.)Κb4�=����"���/��?�'?����+�-t�WB�wt�悔E���]u����9��<w����w'l�撪�p�}��|���e���b-,�1��:{{nn�ʩ�`ug*��"��y��+*��v�.��1�t�t�si?�w8x���d�>Ju�&amp;���`���ak:�9�ڌ9����dnff���nN�M�H�4��u0��.��
=:�Bat,�C#K��s�ƅ�{�%���H�Y���6P��mp�����4ԦZ�� G��Δ�Nl�bĮX��%91TIo9ဒ�,�`�&amp;�N�0Li&amp;ۉ�yL$.�aW�(,��pd���R�g�zj�gNj�wl�N��ӻW���c��Bhkjq��6�"˯4���
���*�-.���o���4�8����I���[���Y���
�Kj7�;kV�$6���U��yѶy��׷����K|���������/�L+Ϸ�y/�y���;��Z��EB(J��&lt;���{ܛ�g��TE*�zHP�+��V��h�f8��Wܹb�{)�����.��.zr�k\25S����$�l�A�U<c���.�d7o��5}qm^�.g��朌�8��y�b��ǐ�dc� ��æ��5���ﺩơ="" )�&���d9p㴦9��v��^"zs���6��������px�e-�h�o�,�q��(�i:���%:��ѱː�,��$0��c="6b�X&#39;ϿtV��;/�O���H�">g�kc�G�d�mxe�=9�3��G���5�E�}��/.������<g��\}�|q�#����5h�w�ł��q����%�&��� �e&�[��!mgxys�1�z:���clĎ_h#��m˩��b$��\ƞ���itt�f$j�fyj�%��%*��lu�owt�w�����="�ti�q�RQ����ze=[(N�Wx���S�\�N���tvR��^��Xh��,�ۗ�i�G�k" s}��n�c��7��z%�c�k�="" *��uqr�ȵr�="" �(�|�m#���+er�띓���n�ث:i�Ɇx�ܦ{�skgwe}w}zlbv���ԙՉ֌��܆�̫�x�="�(5��%[���5�%�n�R������&lt;UY����i��i�s���93l��IO_��.{��6gn��Cז�{��&amp;MV㜂��ܞ" cb�t4��";�9q�="�Y�*�PHςJxJ,�&lt;,C���b�{*77��7WW��+ֱ�C������" ?i="" cx�u��'bz������l����������9�a%s�\="C���3|(��Y�99��R��A�&amp;�yIgY���|�*)�)�����y���9���{��~�1�ŵK�ܵ�w5T�����=��i�:�P" �b�z)��x!�(_="" ٦�w��u������8�5�2v�dn�z�šg����s="" [9��ރp����q%������a:�r�e�w�˘�ӆo�l+��s��liz��|�xof�y�i�s="" ?���u7͝�{l0�½�[j�u�w��~e[�="��Z!ˌ.k�k��.n��MIPS�Ը���t��FY詵�����7;�z�R|�ŷ�8,��)5)�S�R��Sl)lJJv*�9�Д`jr|���ڝZ&amp;K[�eX�굂�U�*�" mj�o����t�`��)�,��rr="" @���p����y��ww_�^_��i�ޢ;yz���v<��{�͓�߶�r9�.��ŝ#]���$30y�lo]�ݺb冚���z;�hyn]ә�pa��x�d}��;���d�z���y�������k�i��7n^�sx="" ]byav����;��dj�uh��y�m��xv�g�="" �qp�e���\��7����������jo��ld?m����lg׳�q-rڭ�c���m1�m��&o4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4es4e��:�?����i�j|(![��!b�b���="">����I��G60a����    �@)����sm�_r    86��b���-�uuW��P�n$���͎��ĵ�N7�^x^�!���=uQ���&lt;���za5�;���)�pk@`ܰ`P��,�n�`̖����(��"�(�{ Ga]���O?��V|��A�ĳ�t�����O���*���sקeZL�/aV-�O��_�g$�
endstream
endobj
18 0 obj
&lt;&gt;stream
x�]��n� ��&lt;o�4��*_�K��m/@�TJM}��x��&gt;��������Ӫ����OZuL9T�-��I�tIY�^���k�������+_�Bz+�(~vW�&gt;�m'Fz��V������1���]�A:���Tw��ٶ=�ݳ(�4��P�XG�V���:�S+ޣֳ��vdu(��Xg��Gl{d@zjC&gt;��y9�gN��k���t[z�Z���e)ܥ7�7yy�
endstream
endobj
19 0 obj
&lt;&gt;
stream
�S.
endstream
endobj
2 0 obj
&lt;&gt;endobj
3 0 obj
&lt;&lt; /Type /Pages /Kids [
7 0 R
] /Count 1
&gt;&gt;
endobj
1 0 obj
&lt;&gt;stream

mntrRGB XYZ acspAPPL���,
desc�|cprtx(wtpt�bkpt�rXYZ�gXYZ�bXYZ�rTRCgTRCbTRCdesc"Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile"Artifex Software sRGB ICC ProfiletextCopyright Artifex Software 2011XYZ �Q�XYZ XYZ o�8��XYZ b����XYZ $����curv
#(-27;@EJOTY^chmrw|�������������������������
%+28&gt;ELRY`gnu|����������������&amp;/8AKT]gqz������������!-8COZfr~���������� -;HUcq~���������
+:IXgw��������'7HYj{�������+=Oat�������2FZn�������      %   :   O   d   y   �   �   �   �   �   �

'
=
T
j
�
�
�
�
�
�"9Qi������*C\u�����


&amp;
@
Z
t
�
�
�
�
�.Id����    %A^z����    &amp;Ca~����1Om����&amp;Ed����#Cc����'Ij����4Vx���&amp;Il����Ae����@e���� Ek���*Qw���;c���*R{���Gp���@j���&gt;i���  A l � � �!!H!u!�!�!�"'"U"�"�"�#
#8#f#�#�#�$$M$|$�$�%    %8%h%�%�%�&amp;'&amp;W&amp;�&amp;�&amp;�''I'z'�'�(
(?(q(�(�))8)k)�)�**5*h*�*�++6+i+�+�,,9,n,�,�--A-v-�-�..L.�.�.�/$/Z/�/�/�050l0�0�11J1�1�1�2*2c2�2�3
3F33�3�4+4e4�4�55M5�5�5�676r6�6�7$7`7�7�88P8�8�99B99�9�:6:t:�:�;-;k;�;�&lt;'<e<�<�="=a=�=�> &gt;`&gt;�&gt;�?!?a?�?�@#@d@�@�A)AjA�A�B0BrB�B�C:C}C�DDGD�D�EEUE�E�F"FgF�F�G5G{G�HHKH�H�IIcI�I�J7J}J�KKSK�K�L*LrL�MMJM�M�N%NnN�OOIO�O�P'PqP�QQPQ�Q�R1R|R�SS_S�S�TBT�T�U(UuU�VV\V�V�WDW�W�X/X}X�YYiY�ZZVZ�Z�[E[�[�\5\�\�]']x]�^^l^�__a_�``W`�`�aOa�a�bIb�b�cCc�c�d@d�d�e=e�e�f=f�f�g=g�g�h?h�h�iCi�i�jHj�j�kOk�k�lWl�mm`m�nnkn�ooxo�p+p�p�q:q�q�rKr�ss]s�ttpt�u(u�u�v&gt;v�v�wVw�xxnx�y*y�y�zFz�{{c{�|!|�|�}A}�~~b~�#���G���
�k�͂0�����W��������G����r�ׇ;����i�Ή3�����d�ʋ0�����c�ʍ1�����f�Ώ6����n�֑?����z���M��� �����_�ɖ4���
�u���L���$�����h�՛B��������d�Ҟ@��������i�ءG���&amp;����v���V�ǥ8��������n���R�ĩ7�������u���\�ЭD���-�������u���`�ֲK�³8���%�������y���h���Y�ѹJ�º;���.���!������
�����z���p���g���_���X���Q���K���F���Aǿ�=ȼ�:ɹ�8ʷ�6˶�5̵�5͵�6ζ�7ϸ�9к�&lt;Ѿ�?���D���I���N���U���\���d���l���v��ۀ�܊�ݖ�ޢ�)߯�6���D���S���c���s�����
������2���F���[���p��������(���@���X���r��������4���P���m��������8���W���w����)���K���m��
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
&lt;&gt;stream
<!--?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?-->
<!--?adobe-xap-filters esc="CRLF"?-->
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP toolkit 2.9.1-13, framework 1.6">
<rdf:rdf xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ix="http://ns.adobe.com/iX/1.0/">
<rdf:description rdf:about="uuid:86fb0a98-6263-11f0-0000-d0aa9c4924b2" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/" pdf:producer="GPL Ghostscript 9.14">
<rdf:description rdf:about="uuid:86fb0a98-6263-11f0-0000-d0aa9c4924b2" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"><xmp:modifydate>2015-07-14T16:40:04Z</xmp:modifydate>
<xmp:createdate>2015-07-14T16:40:04Z</xmp:createdate>
<xmp:creatortool>PDF</xmp:creatortool></rdf:description>
<rdf:description rdf:about="uuid:86fb0a98-6263-11f0-0000-d0aa9c4924b2" xmlns:xapmm="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xapmm:documentid="uuid:86fb0a98-6263-11f0-0000-d0aa9c4924b2">
<rdf:description rdf:about="uuid:86fb0a98-6263-11f0-0000-d0aa9c4924b2" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" dc:format="application/pdf"><dc:title><rdf:alt><rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">document</rdf:li></rdf:alt></dc:title></rdf:description>
</rdf:description></rdf:description></rdf:rdf>
</x:xmpmeta>


<!--?xpacket end='w'?-->
endstream
endobj
xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f 
0000011039 00000 n 
0000010826 00000 n 
0000010980 00000 n 
0000013668 00000 n 
trailer
&lt;&gt;
startxref
146
%%EOF
</e<�<�="=a=�=�></g��\}�|q�#����5h�w�ł��q����%�&���></c���.�d7o��5}qm^�.g��朌�8��y�b��ǐ�dc�></w����w'l�撪�p�}��|���e���b-,�1��:{{nn�ʩ�`ug*��"��y��+*��v�.��1�t�t�si?�w8x���d�></o�z����8></d�2�0e?ʛ�a�1��></gec></x�2��y����0ÿ����-�(vp�ү����kφ�)�c|mezc��></gj������></w�></c7635ddd2c9579cc73483074c45ac3d9><div class="vimiumReset vimiumHUD" style="right: 150px; display: none;"></div></body><div></div></html>
```

Header

```
<!-- saved from url=(0026)http://localhost:5000/test -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>{'content-length': '15212', 'x-robots-tag': 'noindex, nofollow, noimageindex', 'x-dropbox-metadata': '{"rev": "4325329019721", "thumb_exists": false, "path": "/Agenda 7-14-2015.docx", "is_dir": false, "client_mtime": "Tue, 14 Jul 2015 18:29:03 +0000", "icon": "page_white_word", "read_only": false, "modifier": null, "bytes": 22580, "modified": "Tue, 14 Jul 2015 18:29:03 +0000", "size": "22.1 KB", "root": "dropbox", "mime_type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "revision": 275027}', 'x-server-response-time': '219', 'server': 'nginx', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-dropbox-request-id': '14dc0144973a9896429f8e8eb8faf960', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'date': 'Tue, 14 Jul 2015 18:40:39 GMT', 'original-content-length': '15212', 'content-type': 'application/pdf'}<div class="vimiumReset vimiumHUD" style="right: 150px; display: none;"></div></body><div></div></html>
```

And here's a link to the txt output in case that's needed, it didn't fit in the post:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekfo6t6aut6g22d/text.html?dl=0

Essentially I want to know what I'm looking at and if there's anything I can do with it. Let me know if my code isn't clear or if there's anything else I can include!

Comment: Can you share your code and a sample file you see this with?

Comment: Thanks for the updated post. As far as I can tell, this is all working correctly. The header you're getting back is telling you it's a PDF: "'content-type': 'application/pdf'", and the content is valid PDF data. There's some HTML at the top of your "Content" section, but presumably that's from your own test site(?), as I'm not getting that back from the Dropbox API call itself. If you're just trying to display the returned PDF, you can't just print the data out on the page like that, as that'll just been interpreted as text. You'll need to use an iframe or something.

Comment: If you want to display the PDF in an iframe, you can make the API call directly in the src for the iframe, by passing the access token as URL parameter, but that would require exposing the access token to the user, which may or may not be okay in your use case.

Comment: Hi @Greg, thanks for your help. I have in fact been trying to iFrame it (among other strategies, I'm trying anything to get it to work). I think that html was actually returned, if I open it in the browser it doesn't appear but when opened in a text editor it comes up. It seems like it should be frameable but just displays the jibberish pdf data when framed (even if I take out the html and rename it as a pdf). Also can't seem to get any other standard application to display the data of the pdf strangely enough. I'm struggling to see how this part of the API is supposed to be used.

Comment: When supplying an OAuth 2 access token as a URL parameter, you would use the `access_token` parameter. That is, ?`access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE`. You should revoke that token now that you've posted it though.

Comment: Tried putting the source directly in the iframe but can't seem to work around authentication failed even when providing Authorization= "Bearer 7_XHti2LmzYAAAAAAACaPcyc3PpEMJ7KuOgYdCYg3a8u8TV6P9HwCY_6RxIjCrl3" as specified in the header of the request we were sending from the server. Seems like it might be promising if I can get the authentication working? Thanks again –

Comment: Sorry to go on so long, the token doesn't seem to be getting through either. Strange that I'm able to get through to Something on the API but it doesn't seem as strait forward doing it from the front end. @Greg would you recommend I open up another question asking more specifically how to display that type of return data? It appears the /previews function is meant to be framed but I must be framing it incorrectly somehow.

Comment: Yes, if you want to continue with this method make a new post with where you are now. I believe extended discussions like this in comments are discouraged. (For reference though, framing /previews responses directly like this isn't necessarily encouraged.)

Comment: Hi sorry I was just about to open a new post when I noticed you said this approach wasn't encouraged. Before I open the other one, what exactly is the previews response there for then? Because I can't seem to do anything at all (including framing) with it anyways.

Comment: The /previews endpoint allows you to download the content for a preview of the file. In the simplest form, you could test this by writing the content out to a .pdf file, for example, and viewing it.